# "Kids shout at plants" (relation vs implication?)

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I suspect "Kids shout at plants" can be represented as an implication:

(x)(y)[Kx --> (Py --> Sx)]

or as a relation

Skp

Is this correct? Why or why not?

Comment: A relation : **Sxy** translates "x Shouts at y".

Comment: Is the first formal statement an equivalent interpretation of that relation?

Comment: But the formula must be **(x)(y)[Kx → (Py → Sxy)]**.

Comment: I see... so relations can't be expressed as conditionals as well

Comment: A "relation" must be expressed by a suitable *predicate* symbol: a "property" by a *unary* predicate symbol **Px**; a *binary* relation by a binary predicate symbol **Rxy**, and so on.

Comment: You cannot express "Bob Loves Jane" with **L(b) and L(j)**; you need **L(b,j)**.

Answer (score 2):

Better would be:  (x)(y)[K(x) & P(y) --> S(x,y)]

where

K(x) means x is a kid

P(y) means y is a plant

S(x,y) means x shouts at y

Answer (score 1):

Your question in effect relates to the distinction between extensional and intensional relations and the underlying problem of universals. The sentence

1. (∀x)(∀y)[Kx → (Py → Sxy)]

is purely extensional. It is true if everything that is a kid shouts at everything that is a plant. Extensional relations may be just 'accidental'. It may be, for example, that everyone in the train carriage where I sit has brown hair. But if that is so, it is unlikely there is anything stronger than simple demographics at work: most people where I live have brown hair. Accidental generalisations do not support the corresponding counterfactual conditionals. We would not believe that if Donald Trump were in this train carriage, he would have brown hair. Also, sentence 1 would become true if I went on a crusade to exterminate every child who didn't shout at plants, or to exterminate all plants that weren't being shouted at. It would even be trivially true if there were no kids at all, or no plants at all.

But often we wish to express something stronger: a relation between the properties themselves. For example, when we say "all ravens are black", this suggests that there is something about 'ravenhood' that causes 'blackness'. Maybe there are some albino ravens, but for the most part the genetic constitution of ravens disposes them to have black feathers. This fact supports the counterfactual conditional: if this bird were a raven it would be black.

Properties and relations may be extensionally equivalent without being intensionally equivalent. To borrow an example from Quine: if we define 'cordate' to mean a species of animal that has a heart, and 'renate' to be a species of animal that has kidneys, then these two properties are co-extensive, but are not intensionally equivalent and do not mean the same thing. A similar thing can be true of relations. Philosophers who hold to 'property realism' maintain that there are universal properties that exist independently of our thoughts. Some also hold that laws of nature are relations between these universal properties. Laws of nature are not merely extensional in character. "Every body on which no net force acts remains at rest or in a state of constant velocity" is a law, even though for all we know there are no bodies in the universe on which no net force acts, which would make it extensionally trivial.

Thus, expressing "all kids shout at plants" as something like

2. S(K,P)

would suggest that you believe this is something like a law of nature, or at least a widely applicable statement about the dispositional properties of kids. This claim does not seem plausible, though if the example were changed to something like all kids get into mischief, it would probably pass.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably what you mean to say is that every kid shouts at some plant. That is,

```
∀x [Kx → [∃y(Py ∧ Sxy)]] (1)
```

where, as in other replies, K stands for the property of being a kid, P for the property of being a plant, and S for the relation of shouting.

In [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/52676/1909) answer, the proposed formalization,

```
∀x∀y [(Kx ∧ Py) → Sxy] (2)
```

means, instead, that every kid shouts at every plant.

While I believe that (1) is what you had in mind, I wanted to point out that your own proposal

```
Skp (3)
```

is meaningful under the following interpretation: `k` would be a *plural constant* designating a certain plurality of kids; `p` a plural constant designating a certain plurality of plants, and `S` designating the relation of shouting as above. Under this interpretation `Skp` would be as well formed as `Ms`, when used to mean that Socrates is a man.

For the notions of plural constant and plurality see [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/).